# Javascript cookies approval process

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I need to ask the user to accept cookies, i saw an example here `http://www.bmw.fr`. My question is: `What is the process of this thing?` The website works fine without that approval thing, `what is the sense of that?`

Somebody asked me to do that, but in order to do that, i want to understand the process, `can somebody explain the process to me please?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is regulated by law/guidelines that differ in different countries. In the UK these are the guidelines: http://ico.org.uk/for_organisations/privacy_and_electronic_communications/the_guide/cookies

Comment: Thanks, i will check it and if it's usefull i will rate your answere